# Access gradle environment variables in application.yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables

I have a spring boot application, and I want to insert a variable from **gradle.properties** into my application.yaml file
I have this in my gradle.properties

```
version=2521.2442
```

And i want to store this variable in my application.yaml file for spring security password

```
spring:
 security : 
  user: 
   name: admin
   password : admin${version}
```

But when I start my application and print value for password I have this error

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "admin${version}"**
My code look like this

```java
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.wombatscorp.confluence.usermacro"})
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.wombatscorp.confluence.usermacro")
public class AddonApplication {

    @Value("${spring.security.user.password}")
    private String password;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(AddonApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void password() {
        System.out.println("Password : " + password);
    }
}
```

So my question is how I can make this work, and use **version** variable from **gradle.properties** in **application.yaml** file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is properties defined in `gradle.properties` are not translated into a form where spring-boot can find the property via [external configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) (environment variables being one such form).

To demonstrate that, given the `gradle.properties` file you supplied and the following Gradle task:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
tasks.register("demo") {
  doLast {
    println("Environment variable version  = '${System.getenv("version")}'") // will be null
    println("Gradle project properties version = '${properties["version"]}'") // will be the value supplied in gradle.properties
  }
}
```

You can, however, translate properties supplied in `gradle.properties` and supply them as environment variables to the Java process running your spring-boot application like this:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
tasks.bootRun {
  systemProperty("version", properties["version"])
}
```

I should also point out that naming the property `version` can be a bit problematic if your `build.gradle.kts` also specifies a `version`. For example, the default Gradle build generated by [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/):

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
// the rest has been omitted for clarity
group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

will take the version specified above (`0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) over what is specified in `gradle.properties`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, maybe I didn`t understand you correctly, but when I added this code to my build.gradle file,


tasks.bootRun {
    systemProperty("version", properties["version"])
}

I still see this error
Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "${version}"

Comment: What output do you see if you add the `demo` task (above) and run: `./gradlew demo`?